# Terminology of compactly supported functions

Tags: general-topology, functions, terminology

If $X$ is a topological space, a function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be **compactly supported**, iff $\operatorname{supp} f$ is a compact subset of $X$ where 
$$\operatorname{supp} f := \operatorname{clos}\{x \in X : f(x) \neq 0\}.$$
In Analysis one often encounters the following definition of the same notion: If $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is an arbitrary subset, we say that $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ is *compactly supported*, iff 
$$S := \operatorname{clos}\{x \in A : f(x) \neq 0\} \subseteq \operatorname{clos}A$$ is compact. One then has if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and bounded, then $S$ has positive distance from the boundary of $A$.

Now in general, $S \neq \operatorname{supp} f$ when we consider the topological space $X = A$ in the above definition of the support as the two closure are taken in different spaces. My question: **Is there a way to make these two definitions consistent?**

Comment: In the second, the closure ought to be the closure with respect to $A$. Otherwise every function on a bounded set would be compactly supported according to that definition.

Comment: @DanielFischer I use the book by Alt on Functional Analysis, p. 41. There he writes $S \subseteq \operatorname{clos}A$ which suggests that we take the closure in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Maybe my question can be formulated more elementary: What are the compact subsets of an open bounded interval?

Comment: Is that "Lineare Funktionalanalysis" by Hans Wilhelm Alt? I can't find anything pertinent on page 41 (or near) there, but that may be because I have the first edition, and page numbers may have changed since then. Have you a number (chapter + section)? The answer to the question in the comment is pretty tautological. Compactness is an intrinsic property of a topological space, so those are just the compact subsets of the ambient space that happen to be contained in the interval.

Comment: @DanielFischer I used the newest English translation from 2017. I just checked the first edition, it should be on p. 17 but there the wording is different and the above inclusion is not mentioned. Thank you...somehow I thought that maybe also $(a,c]$ is compact in $(a,b)$ with $c < b$.

Comment: A compact subset of an open set in a metric space has a positive distance from the boundary. So a compact subset of $(a,b)$ is contained in $[c,d]$ for some $a < c \leqslant d < b$.

Comment: @DanielFischer More abstractly, if $X$ is a topological space, $A \subseteq X$ is an arbitrary subset and $K \subseteq A$ is compact, then $K \subseteq X$ is compact. Then we can use that the compact subset of the real line are precisely the closed and bounded intervals.

Comment: There are more compact sets than only the intervals. But yes, since compactness is an intrinsic property it doesn't matter if we view it as a subset of $X$ or of the subspace $A$.